# Improvement in the below mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM ***** 
WHERE ((first_appeared_on BETWEEN DATE_SUB( '2015-07-28' , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND '2015-07-28') 
      or (last_appeared_on BETWEEN DATE_SUB( '2015-07-28' , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND '2015-07-28'))
```

In the above query I don't want to type the date (2015-07-28) again and again Can I use a variable and assign that variable a value

day = '2015-07-28';

```
SELECT * FROM ***** 
WHERE ((first_appeared_on BETWEEN DATE_SUB(day , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND day) 
      or (last_appeared_on BETWEEN DATE_SUB( day , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND day))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in MySQL with a [user-defined variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html):

```
SET @day = '2015-07-28';

SELECT * FROM ***** 
WHERE ((first_appeared_on BETWEEN DATE_SUB( @day , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND @day) 
  or (last_appeared_on BETWEEN DATE_SUB( @day , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND @day));
```